# Logic App : HTTP GET Request with path variable

Tags: azure, rest, azure-logic-apps

I have an API with Get Request and having an Path variable, I have tested it in Postman it works fine. I have to call it in logic app but I dont find any tab where I can pass the path variable while calling the Logic app.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out, it is through relative URL . we can check the code from Postman URL after we send the Get request. The URL is modified with the value from Path variable, we have to modify the URL in Logic app accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with @Anshul Dubey, After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this work by changing the url along with the required headers i.e., `{ "Accept": "*/*"}`. Considering `http://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/:id` this to be my url along with the Path variables mentioned. I have used `http://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/1` where I got it from Code snippet of postman to it worked in logic apps.

In Postman:

[image]

In Logic Apps:

[image]

Below is the code view of my logic app:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "Accept": "*/*"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "http://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/1"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```